# New Date().toISOString() issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is a strange issue. In my mongodb, I have ISODate something like this:

```
ISODate("1937-08-03T00:00:00.000Z")
```

in my find, I am doing

```
var isoString = new Date(inputDate).toISOString();
db.collection.find({dob: new Date(isoString)})

'inputDate' cab be yyyy-MM-dd or MM/dd/yyyy
```

when I convert string that is user inputted '1937-08-03' using Date().toISOString(), so I get

```
1937-08-03T00:00:00.000Z
```

but when my date format changes to 08/03/1937, using Date().toISOString(), I see ISO string as

```
1937-08-03T04:00:00.000Z
```

if you notice, I see 4 hours added when my date format changed to MM/dd/yyyy from yyyy-MM-dd. so obviously with extra 4 hours added, I am not able to pull the record from the db (no match)

How do I work this?

I am using Node and mongo. Thanks for any help.

Comment: The 4 hours are added 'cause it's you're timezone offset. Convert the time to UTC time and it'll be resolved.

Comment: Peter4499, thanks. How do I convert to UTC? any sample you can put it here. I am about to do a google as well

Comment: So I tried, dob = new Date(inputDate).toUTCString() but the same issues (adding 4 hours more when my date format is MM/dd/yyyy)

Comment: The problem is that [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) (which is called by the `Date` constructor when passing a string) uses different time zone assumptions based on the format of the string.

Comment: JohnnyHK, oh wow.. did not know that. any suggestion for work around?

Comment: The typical recommendation is to use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to give you more control.

Comment: @JBone sorry for the late response. But the ISO way of specifing timezone is as follows:  "2007-04-05T12:30-00:00", so I would try appending "-00:00" to isoString before this line `db.collection.find({dob: new Date(isoString)})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here is how I handled the work around. I know my input date formats are either MM/dd/yyyy or MM-dd-yyyy so I split the string based on / OR - using the regex, and then reformatted back to yyyy-mm-dd format which works fine. If anyone has better solution, please post it here.

```
var dtArray = inputDate.split(/-|\//);
var dtStr = dtArray[2]+'-'+dtArray[0]+'-'+dtArray[1];
```